# How to make write operations to a file faster

Tags: file, go

I am trying to write a large amount of data to a file but it takes quite some time. I have tried 2 solutions but they both take same amount of time. Here are the solutions I have tried;

Solution A:

```
f, err := os.Create("file.txt")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer f.Close()
w := bufio.NewWriter(f)
for _, d := range data {
  bb, err := w.WriteString(fmt.Sprint(d + "\n"))
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
  }
}
err = w.Flush()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Solution B:

```
e, err := os.OpenFile(filePath, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0666)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer e.Close()
for _, d := range data {
    _, err = e.WriteString(d)
    err = e.Sync()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

Any other suggestion on how I can make this write operation faster?

Comment: Disk write _are_ slow an limited by _hardware_ you cannot write faster that what your hardware allows.

Comment: @Volker My hardware is very good. I am just surprise it takes a lot of time to write to a file. No improvements can be made to my solutions?

Comment: Use buffered io like in solution A and that's it. It's impossible to make disk writes faster. Btw. You just talk about "a lot of time" and "my hardware is very good" but never state actual numbers: How many bytes take how long? What is `data`: A slice or a channel. Maybe data is a channel which just doesn't deliver the data fast enough? You really have to provide **much** more detail and numbers and how you invoke your code and what system you are on and how your disks are attached, etc. if you need help.

Comment: @Volker Data here is a slice of strings. Each iteration takes about 600bytes and the whole process takes 12 mins.

Comment: And how long is the slice? How big is the resulting file?

Comment: @Volker 11973 long and the resulting file has a size of ~13MB

Comment: Writing 13MByte to disk doesn't need minutes. Whatever your problem is, it's not the code you showed. You will either have to provide the full details of what you are doing on what system, debug it yourself or live with 12 minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245857/discussion-between-shekwo-and-volker).

Answer (score 0):

I think `bufio` is your friend, as it can help to reduce the number of sys calls required to write the data to disk. You are already using it as part of solution A, however note the default buffer size is 4K. If you want to try larger buffer sizes you can use `NewWriterSize()` to set a larger buffer for the writer.

See https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#NewWriterSize

Based on your solution A I have created a benchmark test you can use for experimenting with different buffer sizes. For the test I am using a data set of 100k records of 600 bytes written to the file. The results I get on my machine for 10 repetitive calls of the FUT with various buffer sizes are as follows:

```
BenchmarkWriteTest/Default_Buffer_Size
BenchmarkWriteTest/Default_Buffer_Size-10                 15      73800317 ns/op
BenchmarkWriteTest/Buffer_Size_16K
BenchmarkWriteTest/Buffer_Size_16K-10                     21      55606873 ns/op
BenchmarkWriteTest/Buffer_Size_64K
BenchmarkWriteTest/Buffer_Size_64K-10                     25      49562057 ns/op
```

As you can see the number of iterations in the test interval (first number) increases significantly with larger buffer size. Accordingly the time spent per operation drops.

https://gist.github.com/mwittig/f1e6a81c2378906292e2e4961f422870

Answer (score -1):

Combine all your data into a single string, and write that in one operation. This will avoid the overhead of filesystem calls.